# Why is my game scene getting errors when the main scene is actually the menu in Godot

Tags: godot

I am adding a main menu to my game. The thing I am doing is adding them in a scene and then changing the scene to the game scene. However, my game has errors which belong to other scenes that do not have an instance in the existing scene. I get errors such as:

```
Invalid get index 'HasEntered' (on base: 'null instance').
```

My entire project is here: https://github.com/Ripple-Studios/Godot-Wild-Jam-36-Game-Ripple-Studios

I would appreciate if someone would help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the linked code.

What is happening is that the practice of getting nodes of the parent has come back to bite you. I'm talking code that looks like this:

```
get_parent().get_node(...)
```

---

You have an scene (HospitalScene.tscn) instanced in your main scene (MainMenu.tscn), which has code similar to the shown above.

The particular error you refer to comes from code that looks like this:

```
func _on_Area2D_body_entered(body):
    var HospitalPosition = get_parent().get_node("Hospital")

    
    if HospitalPosition.HasEntered == true:
        HospitalPosition.isInHospital = false
```

*This code is firing at the start because the `Area2D` is overlapping an `StaticBody`.*

The code is trying to get a sibling `"Hospital"` which does not exist in the scene tree. And thus `HospitalPosition` is null. And trying to access `HospitalPosition.HasEntered` when `HospitalPosition` is null results in the error you mention:

```
Invalid get index 'HasEntered' (on base: 'null instance').
```

---

The scene is trying to reach a node outside of itself. And there is no guarantee that the scene will be instanced where such node is available. Thus, in each and every case of `get_parent().get_node(...)` this could happen.

In fact, when running the game, I get four error that look like this (but with different paths):

```
E 0:00:01.494   get_node: (Node not found: "Hospital" (relative to "/root/CanvasLayer/ParentSprite/Control").)
  <C++ Error>   Condition "!node" is true. Returned: nullptr
  <C++ Source>  scene/main/node.cpp:1325 @ get_node()
  <Stack Trace> HospitalScene.gd:28 @ _on_Area2D_body_entered()
```

You could use `get_node_or_null` instead of `get_node` and check for `null`.

*You could also export `NodePath` variables instead of hard-coding the paths.*

---

Better decoupling strategies than checking if instances are valid include:

- Connect to the signal from outside the scene. It is a common pattern in Godot to call down the scene tree, and signal up the scene tree. See [Node communication (the right way)](https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/basics/node_communication/).
- Connect all the signals through an Autoload (singleton). Which is another common pattern in Godot called a Signal Bus or Event Bus. See [Best practices: Godot GDScript - Event Bus](https://www.gdquest.com/docs/guidelines/best-practices/godot-gdscript/event-bus/).